# Symfony 4 type: The option "0" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I found an answer to a similar problem than mine, but I don't understand how it works and what should I change in my code. So I ask you for help, I have this error message :

> The option "0" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "help", "help_attr", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".

Here is my Type:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Equipment;
use App\Entity\Property;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PropertyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('propertyCategory', ChoiceType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => [
                    'Appartement' => 'Appartement',
                    'Maison' => 'Maison',
                    'Garage' => 'Garage',
                    'Bureau' => 'Bureau',
                    'Château' => 'Château',
                    'Commerce' => 'Commerce',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('uniqueName', TextType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Nom unique'])
            ->add('address', TextType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Adresse'])
            ->add('city', TextType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Ville'])
            ->add('zipcode', IntegerType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Code postal'])
            ->add('country', CountryType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Pays'])
            ->add('surfaceInSquareMeter', IntegerType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Surface en m²'
            ])
            ->add('numberOfPiece', IntegerType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Nombre de pièces'])
            ->add('description', TextType::class, ['required' => false, 'Description'])
            ->add('equipments', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Equipements',
                [
                    'class' => Equipment::class,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'choice_label' => 'name'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('locationCategory', ChoiceType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => [
                    'Meublé' => 'Meublé',
                    'Non meublé' => 'Non meublé',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('rentExcludingCharges', NumberType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Loyer hors charges'
            ])
            ->add('charges', NumberType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Charges'])
            ->add('purchasePrice', NumberType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Prix d\'achat']);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Property::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Hope you understand my english and someone can help me (and explain me how to avoid to do this mistake again)

Thx

EDIT : there was a problem with those useless[] in

```
->add('equipments', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Equipements',
            [
                'class' => Equipment::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            ]
        ])
```

, I resolved it but error message is same

Comment: I didn't see that, thx ! I deleted those useless [] and did a correct indentation but problem is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have missing label attribut:

```
->add('description', TextType::class, ['required' => false, 'Description'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem, but in my case it was because I had an empty option in my form... Might help someone out in the future :)

```php
$builder
    ->add('prijsPerVertoning', MoneyType::class, [
        'currency' => 'EUR',
        'divisor'  => 1000,
        '' // <---- this breaks functionality
    ])->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too few [] in:

```
->add('equipments', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Equipements',
            //[
                'class' => Equipment::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            //]
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

SYMFONY 6.2

when building a form,

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $classData, ['']);
```

and passing 3rd argument as above

same error apear THE OPTION 0 DOES NOT EXIST

if you pass third argument as [''] in symfony up to 6.1 - it will work, from 6.2 does not.